# Boost 5V to 18V: charge pump + LDO or conventional boost converter?

Tags: h-bridge, boost, charge-pump

I am trying to build a H-bridge driver using discrete parts. Now I have a problem regarding generating the 10+V gate voltage for the NMOSFETs I used.

The H-bridge and its controls is like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAm923.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My question is, how do I generate this +18V rail? DC-DC Boost converter, or charge pump to ~20V and LDO it down a bit?

Don't worry about my 5V rail, it is capable of 30+ amperes.

Comment: Can you use PMOS on top? Then you would not need to generate a special voltage to turn them on.

Comment: PMOS have a lower current rating and larger Rds(on). This will cause problems.

Comment: Did you look at real PMOS parts, or are you assuming?

Comment: I searched on digikey. I found many parts that have Rds < 44 mOhm and Id larger than 33A. I didn't find anything in same TO220 package, though. What is your max current anyway? And will you be in volume production?

Comment: What will be the switching frequency of the H-bridge?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Several hundred kilohertz maybe, PWM from 8MHz ATmega.

Comment: @mkeith Max current about 20A. No volume production yet but very tight budget. I have bought a sample of `IRF4905` and measured those against `IRF510` and `IRF540`, both I have a stock of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple boost converter would probably be the easiest for the currents involved.

Those drivers are not going to be the best- fast turn on + slow turn off = lots of shoot-through.

Comment: Then how to reduce the shoot through then? I can reduce the gate pull-up resistors.

Comment: The easy and expensive way is to use gate driver ICs such as those from IRF that include dead time as well as push-pull drive. If you don't want to do that, use a push-pull driver (two MOSFETs rather than a MOSFET and a resistor) or a similar circuit with two BJTs. Either will be better than what you have. Consider inserting  small delays (100 ns or whatever) to allow the opposing power MOSFETs to switch off.

Comment: And the IC way is what I cannot afford to do. I know very well about those ICs when going through IRF portfolio searching for power MOSFETs that fits my need but those are just too expensive. About push/pull driver my microcontroller only have 5V output, how to make that work?

Comment: Add another transistor instead of the resistor- three transistors per driver. One (plus a resistor) for the level shifter and two complementary transistors to drive the gate.

Comment: Rephrase this, open drain inverter circuit for level shifting, push-pull inverter circuit for driving the gate, right?

Comment: @MaxthonChan Yes, exactly right.